# Is any reflector from a presheaf category $PSh(K)$ to a topos $C$ necessarily left exact?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

Let $C$ be a topos, $K$ a small category and
$$
PSh(K) \leftrightarrows C 
$$
a [reflective subcategory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflective+subcategory) with inclusion $i\colon C\hookrightarrow PSh(K)$ and reflector $T$.

> Is $T$ left exact?

$D$ being a topos is equivalent to the existence of a (probably different) reflective adjunction
$$
PSh(K) \leftrightarrows D 
$$
with a left exact reflector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the functor $\Delta : \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{sSet}$ that sends each set $X$ to the discrete simplicial set on $X$. This is certainly fully faithful, and it has a left adjoint, namely the functor $\pi_0 : \mathbf{sSet} \to \mathbf{Set}$ that sends a simplicial set to its set of connected components. It is not hard to check that $\pi_0 : \mathbf{sSet} \to \mathbf{Set}$ does *not* preserve monomorphisms in general – so it does not preserve finite limits either.